# Automated contact filtering for event attendees?

Tags: civievent, profile

Is there a way to perform automated actions when people sign up to events based on their profile info?

For example: 
- if someone has already attended an event in the last month, put them on the waiting list
- if someone belongs to a particular organisation, automatically mark them as registered

I'm using Civi 4.2.27 on Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a plugin that hooks into `civicrm_post` that will allow you to do anything you like with the newly-registered contact.

```
add_action( 'civicrm_post', 'my_do_stuff_after_registration', 10, 4 );
function my_do_stuff_after_registration( $op, $objectName, $objectId, $objectRef ) {
    if ( $op != 'create' ) return;
    if ( $objectName != 'Participant' ) return;
    $contact_id = $objectRef['contact_id'];
    // ... do anything you like with this contact
}
```